# ¿cómo combinar columnas de dos hojas diferentes?

Tags: excel

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: Tengo una hoja de cálculo con los datos de los alumnos de una clase. Una columna es por ejemplo DNI, otra nombre, otro apellidos, otra(s) columnas con calificaciones de diferentes exámenes.

Por otro lado, tengo otra hoja con alumnos de otra asignatura, con el mismo esquema. En esta hoja hay alumnos que están en la otra asignatura también y otros no.

¿Puedo combinar los datos de ambas hojas en una sola, que estaría formada por los alumnos que están en ambas asignaturas, y con Todas las columnas de notas (es para poder hacer las medias)? 
He visto que en Excel hay una función que podría servir (consolidar datos), pero no me funciona como es debido

La hoja 1 y la hoja 2 pueden tener columnas diferentes. Por ejemplo la hoja 2 puede tener una variable que es "examen sobre excel" (información que quiero pasar a la hoja 1) pero otra variable "examen sobre windows" (que no quiero pasar). 
Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias

Comment: Bienvenido. Si bien las algunas características de las aplicaciones de hoja de cálculo son comunes hay otras que no lo son por lo que generalmente es conveniente especificar a cuál aplicación se refiere la pregunta y eso implica usar la etiqueta de esa aplicación y no las de otras.. Por otro lado al decir "no funciona como es debido" sin proporcionar los detalles deja la duda acerca de si las estas usando correctamente. Por cierto, es conveniente que sigas [tour] y revises [ask]. Nota al margen: Dado que en el cuerpo de la pregunta se menciona Excel, voy a eliminar la otra etiqueta.

Comment: perdón por los errores, y gracias por corregirlas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar la "consolidación" de 2 hojas diferentes en Microsoft Excel (tablas con las mismas columnas) te recomiendo lo siguiente :

1. Copia el contenido de la hoja 2 (sin los títulos) en la hoja 1.
2. Selecciona los datos con sus nombres de columnas, los copias (ctrl + c)
3. Pegas los datos en la primera hoja (ctrl + v)
4. Anda a la pestaña "Datos", apartado "Herramientas de datos" & selecciona "quitar duplicados", eso dejará los registros que son únicos (asumiendo que no se repiten los alumnos entre hojas con diferente data). Lo que hace esta herramienta es dejar todas las filas únicas.

Comment: gracias, pero creo que no me serviria. La hoja 1 y la hoja 2 pueden tener columnas diferentes. Por ejemplo la hoja 2 puede tener una variable que es "examen sobre excel" (información que quiero pasar a la hoja 1) pero otra variable "examen sobre windows" (que no quiero pasar).

Comment: @BlancoSaco: Está muy bien que comentes sobre la utilidad de las respuestas. Cuando te das cuenta que algo no ha quedada claro sobre la pregunta, se deberían agregar los detalles adicionales a la pregunta misma. Mira los comentarios como notas adhesivas /post its de uso provisional.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [Consolidar datos en varias hojas de cálculo](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Consolidar-datos-en-varias-hojas-de-c%C3%A1lculo-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b) hay dos formas de realizar la función de consolidación de datos, por posición o bien por categoría.

Me parece que la que te podría ser es por categoría, sólo asegúrate que los títulos de las columnas sean los mismos.